# When I Add A Color To An Object It's Always Transparent When Rendering

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, shaders, color

When I add a color to an object it's always transparent when rendering or gray in viewport shading tab.
What should I do?

[image]
[image]

Comment: one possibility is, that your alpha value is 0

Comment: I dont think just by adding color, something like this can happen. Please share your file via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com to let us see your file setup.

Comment: ..Or its collection is set to 'Holdout'?

Comment: @Robin Betts The Outliner looks like the cube is not in a collection. But I guess you're right with the holdout, presumably _Object Properties > Visibility > Holdout_ is enabled.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann  .. ahh! well spotted! It's still only a 'maybe', I guess..

Comment: @Robin Betts Definitely maybe ;) It looks strange because the object holdout seems like the view is set to _Film > Transparent_, but what looks like the normal grey background is still there... maybe there's a plane behind the object blocking out the transparent background?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Indeed.. that's the only way I could reproduce this, when I tried it at home.. but couldn't turn that into a 'for sure' answer.

Comment: Yes, a blend file would be helpful. To reproduce it seems much easier to do on purpose than by mistake :D